# Why is my app-console-generated access token expiring?

Tags: dropbox-api

Using the App Console, I am generating an Access Token for use by my java application.

Why is my access token expiring? It worked yesterday but today I get the below error.

How do I get a permanent token for my application to use? (Usage is similar to a "Google Service Account" that generates a permanent token.)

Exception:

```
InvalidAccessTokenException

{
    "error_summary": "expired_access_token/...", 
    "error": {
        ".tag": "expired_access_token"
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2022 12 02:

Thanks for the below information and links. After about 5 hours of working on wrapping my brain around the concepts and the example code, I finally got something working by doing the following:

(1) Using the example code and manual process at https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/authorize/ShortLiveTokenAuthorize.java I obtained an auth code.

(2) I then wrote java code to post the auth code to the https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token end point and receive tokens including the refresh token.

(3) I then wrote code to post the refresh token to the same end point to receive an access token.

It appears I can hold on to the refresh token and repeat step 3 to get access tokens each time.

HOWEVER, I must be missing something here.

This is WAY too much extra work that should be done either by the App Console and/or the SDK.

Also, it seems to me that a “Client Credentials Flow” should be available in the API and SDK.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox is in the process of switching to only issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).

The [official Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) can actually handle the process for you automatically, as long as you supply the necessary credentials, e.g., as shown retrieved in [the examples here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/authorize).